# JSR223 Post Processor: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.bsf.engines.java.JavaEngine

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to use a JSR223 post processor in jmeter 2.11 with some java code and I keep getting this error:

```
org.apache.bsf.BSFManager:Exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.bsf.engines.java.JavaEngine
```

I've checked the bsf/bsh jar files, not sure what else I need to do to make this work. I've read that groovy is recommended but I'd really like this to work with java.

Answer (score 0):

As per the very first lines from [BSF Sampler documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler):

> See the Apache Bean Scripting Framework website for details of the languages supported. You may need to download the appropriate jars for the language; they should be put in the JMeter lib directory.

And at the same place:

> The BSF API has been largely superseded by JSR-223, which is included in Java 1.6 onwards. Most scripting languages now include support for JSR-223; please use the JSR223 Sampler instead. The BSF Sampler should only be needed for supporting legacy languages/test scripts.

So I would recommend considering the following (in the order from worst to best performance provided)

1. [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) (if your Java code is doing something "light")
2. [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) + groovy language - for "heavy" operations (again you'll need to have groovy jar in your JMeter CLASSPATH)
3. Write your own implementation of [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) Sampler

Both Beanshell and Groovy support Java syntax with some limitations which can be easily worked around.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide which might help you to make right selection.